# React Date Picker - How to handle if user only selects the start date in range and does not selects the end date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I want to keep the end date as start date if user does select only start date but not end date in range date picker, but if user selects start date and also end date then end date should not be start date. How to resolve this?

Comment: as soon as user selects `starts date` and if he is going to `endDate` set `minDate=start date + 1`

Comment: This won't solve, cause min date means the minimum number that can be selected